# How to route multiple static pages in Zend

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

In my routes.ini file i have these routes  and there will be many more similar to this how can i make one route that will wor all or some method ?

```
 ;howitworks
routes.howitworks.route = "howitworks.html"
routes.howitworks.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.howitworks.defaults.action = "howitworks"


;howtopost
routes.howtopost.route = "howtopost.html"
routes.howtopost.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.howtopost.defaults.action = "howtopost"


;terms & conditions
routes.howtopost.route = "terms.html"
routes.howtopost.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.howtopost.defaults.action = "terms"
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Zend Framework are you using?

I'm going to assume ZF1.12 - [Zend Framework 1.12 - Using Zend_Config for Routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.add-config)

```
routes.page.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.page.route = "([a-z0-9]+)\.html"
routes.page.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.page.map.action = 1
```

I think what you are after is the above - it is doing a regex check for lower-case letters and numbers that end in .html (for example "howitworks.html"). The Action is then set as the captured parameter (in this example, howitworks).

I vaguely recall trying this myself when I first started playing with routing - I think there's an issue using the .html at the end of the route? I ended up doing routing through the bootstrap file.

I hope this helps :)

### [Edit]

Thinking about the problem of removing `.html` from the string being sent to the action, I remember I couldn't. What I did was pump all my pages into a single action with the url as a parameter, then did some logic in the controller to call the correct page.

```
routes.page.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.page.route = "([a-z0-9]+)\.html"
routes.page.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.page.defaults.action = "page"
routes.page.map.url = 1
```

And in the `pageAction` function I would retrieve the url parameter (`$this->getRequest()->getParam('url');`), strip the `.html` off the end and do something with the result (in my case I fetched the page from the database based on the url)

Comment: I get thsi error Message: Invalid controller specified  abc.html

Comment: I think that was the error I used to get as well. I had to change the route by removing `\.html` from the end to make it work. Problem with that approach was that the route was grabbing all top-level urls.

Comment: Well i want to use this urls as route other wise i have already done this using page method youre reffereing too